# Unable to create hibernate.cfg.xml through eclipse wizard?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, wildfly

The eclipse wizard that is supposed to guide me through creating a hibernate configuration file greys out its Next button, until I manually check the option to generate a Console Configuration. Is this how it works?

Next, I get into the Create Hibernate Console Configuration wizard, which has the same problem: I complete its Main tab, Next remains grey, and Finish does nothing for me. I expect to see some kind of warning as to what is missing here, but the wizard is not very helpful here.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the JBoss Tools Create Hibernate Configuration Wizard: pressing Finish generates an unhandled event loop exception in eclipse. A workaround is to select an older hibernate version.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Hibernate version to 5.2

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in hibernate tools. One hack is that when you are setting up configuration file and the dialog box freezes you can just click anywhere on screen and cancel the edit configuration dialog. That would allow you to setup your hibernate.cfg.xml file.